# Latex - How to change style of this table of content?

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

I am working with the documentclass amsart and I am trying to build up a document just with `\section` and `\subsection`, but without `\part`.

I am working with the first code and I am trying hard to change it into the style of the table of contents of the second code. That means:

- an appropriate spacing between sections
- sections in bold type and a little bit bigger

Is there any possibility? Thank you very much in advance !

**First code:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=35mm,right=25mm,top=40mm,bottom=40mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%
\newpage
\section{First Section}

\subsection{First Subsection}

\subsection{Second Subsection}

\section{Second Section}

\end{document}
```

**Second code:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=35mm,right=25mm,top=40mm,bottom=40mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
%
\newpage
\part{First Section}

\section{First Subsection}

\section{Second Subsection}

\part{Second Section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the definition of tocline a little bit ... the idea is to write the title only to the toc file if depth is > -1 (-1 equals parts, 0 equals chapters and so on)

To format the sections, adjust `\l@section`, a bit more space, bold font etc.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=35mm,right=25mm,top=40mm,bottom=40mm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\l@section{\@tocline{1}{12pt plus2pt}{0pt}{}{\bfseries}}% <- added

\def\@tocline#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\relax
    \ifnum #1>-1% <- added
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth % then omit
  \else
    \par \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{#2}%
    \begingroup \hyphenpenalty\@M
    \@ifempty{#4}{%
      \@tempdima\csname r@tocindent\number#1\endcsname\relax
    }{%
      \@tempdima#4\relax
    }%
    \parindent\z@ \leftskip#3\relax \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\relax
    \rightskip\@pnumwidth plus4em \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
    #5\leavevmode\hskip-\@tempdima #6\nobreak\relax
    \hfil\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\@tocpagenum{#7}}\par
    \nobreak
    \endgroup
  \fi% <- added
\fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
%
\newpage
\part{First Section}

\section{First Subsection}

\section{Second Subsection}

\part{Second Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(changes in the code are marked with % <- added)

Comment: Thank you very much !! I have one more question: Is there a way to make a clickable table of content?

Comment: @SimonBr Add `\usepackage{hyperref}` before `\begin{document}`